# How to crop an image before loading it with load_img?

Tags: python, keras

I need to crop the bottom of an image before loading and resizing it in load_img.
This is what I mean:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img(image_path ,target_size = (350, 350))
```

my goal here is to first crop the image_path, then pass it to load_img. How can I do so?

Comment: crop using `crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]` and save it back to the `image_path` before using `image.load_img()`

Comment: @olahsymbo goal here is to load the img just once. So I'm looking for a solution to be able to crop inside load_img itself.

Comment: I'm not sure if we can edit the main source file and add the crop function. I've never tried it. Here is the main source code for `load_img()`: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L261-L296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, here it is:

```
test_image = image.load_img(image_path)
test_image =     test_image.crop((0,0,test_image.size[0],test_image.size[1]-10))
test_image = test_image.resize((350,350))
```

Comment: bravo to myself!

Comment: how does this first crop the `image_path`, then pass it to `load_img` function? as mentioned in your question. Instead you are first loading the image  with `load_img` and then cropping, which is the most obvious solution